# Identify JsonPrimitve is BigDecimal or Integer using JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I trying to identify the value from JsonPrimitve is BigDecimal or Integer or Long or int or double but not getting the exact specific type.

```
JsonPrimitive jpri = jsonElement.getAsJsonPrimitive();
if(jpri.isString()){
    String str = jpri.getAsString();
} else if(jpri.isNumber()) {
    //Here I want to know at the runtime what type of value jpri holds. 
    //I tried below but no luck
    Number number = jpri.getAsNumber();
    if(number instanceof Integer)
        Integer int = jpri.getAsInteger();
    else if(number instanceof BigDecimal)
        Integer int = jpri.getAsBigDecimal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try following two approaches

1)

```
 Number number = (Number) jpri.value;
  if (number instanceof Integer){

  }else if(number instanceof BigDecimal){
  
   }
```

2. 

```
else if (jpri.isNumber()) {
  Number number = jpri.getAsNumber();
  double numberValue= number.doubleValue();
  if ((int) numberValue== numberValue) {
    return Integer.valueOf((int) numberValue);
  } else if ((long) numberValue== numberValue) {
    return Long.valueOf((long) numberValue);
  } else if ((float) numberValue== numberValue) {
    return Float.valueOf((float) numberValue);
  } else {
    return Double.valueOf((double) numberValue);
  }
```

Comment: JSON is not limited by IEEE 754 doubles. What if the given number is or `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`?

Comment: You will probably lose format as well digits which will affect to a different number. First approach I added should also work in that example.

Comment: @devadrion - I have already tried both the solutions and Number is of type LazilyParsedNumber so its not working ..

Comment: @Ganesh issue is that JSON does not distinguish between type or is limited to a size. It simple save it as text. Do you know what numbers you are getting like what size and format ?